# Cannot import installed python package (MacOS)

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I cannot import any python package when running python on Visual Studio code or on my Terminal. I can still do this if I were to code on a Jupyter notebook. However, when I tried other environment that doesn't use the notebook server. It returns me ModuleNotFound Error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/truongminh/Desktop/DataScience/Datasets/CityU Text/test_PreprocessText.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PreprocessText
  File "/Users/truongminh/Desktop/DataScience/Datasets/CityU Text/PreprocessText.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Most of my packages was download via anaconda. I don't know if it might be the cause of this.

Comment: Have you activated your conda environment by `condo activate <env>` before you run your script?

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you so muchhh